# add dns records for unfamilliar registrar

Tags: dns

I am trying to add a DNS TXT record to my domain that i bought, yet the company I bought it from doesn't have an option to add DNS records in their user interface..

Is there a way I can add records using cmd or an external software?

My domain is found in the WhoIs system and the registrar information is the following:

registrar name: Peligon Ltd

registrar info: http://www.webline.co.il/

I need it to approve my domain from firebase

Comment: Hey was wondering if you had a chance to look at my answer and if you have any more questions? If none and it satisfies you, appreciate if you could vote up or mark as answer, as applicable...

Comment: Saw it just now, this is what i did (transferred the domain) and it worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to point your domain nameservers to Cloudflare. [Create a free account on Cloudflare and add your domain](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/201720164-Creating-a-Cloudflare-account-and-adding-a-website). You will be given two nameservers that will need to be configured by the registrar. Even if there's no UI, they should still be able to configure this on their end or at worst go to the parent registrar and get them to do it. This process can take time but it's worth it in the long run.

Once the whole process completed (can take up to 48hrs for any nameservers or DNS changes, sometimes longer for small registrars whi are not very active), you will have full access to manage all DNS aspect of your domain. All DNS records will be in your total control. You will only need to deal with the registrar for your domain renewal.

When using Cloudflare, you don't need to turn on the orange cloud - it's just good to have but if you only need to manage DNS, you can turn that off and start managing it right away.